# IIS Third Party Certificate Insallation

Tags: iis, certificate

I have a certificate generated by Salesforce with crt extension

I exported it to a .cer file on windows (open it -> Details -> copy to path )

I've installed cer file on IIS Manager

I had an error

> Cannot find the certificate request associated with this certificate file

I followed the corresponding [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/959216)

Now I know my certificate is installed and I have a Friendly name for it, but it still not appearing in IIS.

How can I make a certificate installed on Windows appear in IIS certificates ?

**Edit**

More about how I got the certificate. There are two companies, one that work with Salesforce and mine.

We are trying to consume a WCF Service from Salesforce Apec Callout.

We choose Transport security with certificate authentication.

For that purpose salesforce team provide a certificate they created, I don't know how. I didn't provide any private key. I guess it's a certificate without official CA.

I'm trying to install it on server were my WCF service is hosted by IIS.

Comment: You need to merge your private key with the .cer file to get a .pfx file and then import into IIS.

Comment: I'm trying to export certificate as pfx, but this option is greyed out. Only .cer and .p7b are available.

Comment: you will have to get started from scratch. Greyed out option means this certificate does not allow itself to export and move to another machine. You need to generate another certificate.

Comment: Say I ask Salesforce team to provide a new crt. Why should the new one work better ? Do I have to specify anything for my request ?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/06/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-77-588-510-0-after-installing-it-why/ you might check if you do request the certificate the right way.

Comment: I edited my post about how I got the certificate

Comment: @LexLi thank to your post, I understand that once installed, the certificate do not appear in IIS because it does not have a private key.